# Как вставить значения переменных в запрос на запись в базу данных MYSQL в Python?

Tags: python, mysql

Не выходит передать переменную в MySQL. Код был списан с документации. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

```
add_unit2 = ("INSERT INTO unit "
             "(unit_ip, unit_name, unit_mac) "
             "VALUES (%(ip)s, %(name)s, %(mac)s)")

data_salary = {
  'ip': ip,
  'name': name,
  'mac': mac,
}
cursor.execute(add_unit2, data_salary)
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? "Не выходит передать" - что значит? Что происходит не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось передать через

`add_unit = ("INSERT INTO unit " "(unit_ip, unit_name, unit_mac) " "VALUES ('%(ip)s', '%(name)s', '%(mac)s')" % {'ip': ip, 'name': name, 'mac': mac}) cursor.execute(add_unit)`

Comment: Это плохой способ решить проблему. Он уязвим к [sql injection](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)